Formatting of custom list using enumitem messing up argument check
Problem
I want to create a custom list that works like an enumerate list, except that if the optional argument is supplied (i.e., \item[...]), I want the optional argument to be appended to the label that is already there (see example below). This works as intended, but the problem is that when no optional argument is supplied (i.e., just \item), it still shows the formatting that should only be used when the optional argument is supplied.
In the example below, Axiom 3 and Axiom 4 should not be followed by the ()..
MWE
Code
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{axioms}{enumerate}{1}

\NewDocumentCommand{\axiomformatting}{m}{%
    \stepcounter{axiomsi}%
    \IfBlankTF{#1}%
        {\bfseries Axiom \arabic{axiomsi}}% No argument provided
        {{\bfseries Axiom \arabic{axiomsi}} ({\itshape {#1}}).}%
}

\setlist[axioms,1]{
    label={},  % to not increment the counter before `\axiomformatting`, especially when no optional arg. provided, but not working as intended either
    ref={\arabic*},
    align={left},
    format={\axiomformatting},
    itemindent={0.5\leftmargin},
}

\title{\TeX{}.SE MWE}
\author{BrightBulb123}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{axioms}
    \item[ABC Law] Lorem
    \item[DEF Law] Ipsum
    \item Dolor% Shouldn't be showing the "()." in the output
    \item Sit% Shouldn't be showing the "()." in the output
    \item[GHI Law] Amet
\end{axioms}

\end{document}

Image


If you don't supply an argument, the default is supplied. That default is \@itemlabel. That's not considered "blank", and that's why your test for \IfBlank fails.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{axioms}{enumerate}{1}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\axiomformatting}{m}{%
  % #1 = argument supplied (\@itemlabel if no argument supplied)
  \ifx\@itemlabel #1
    % axiomsi counter automatically stepped if no argument is supplied
    \unskip{\bfseries Axiom~\arabic{axiomsi}}%
  \else
    \stepcounter{axiomsi}% Manually step axiomsi when argument supplied
    \unskip{\bfseries Axiom~\arabic{axiomsi}}~({\itshape #1}).%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\setlist[axioms,1]{
  label={},
  ref={\arabic*},
  align={left},
  format={\axiomformatting},
  itemindent={0.5\leftmargin},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{axioms}
  \item[ABC Law] Lorem
  \item[DEF Law] Ipsum
  \item Dolor
  \item Sit
  \item[GHI Law] Amet
\end{axioms}

\end{document}

The above works, unless you pass the option \@itemlabel to \item. But who would do that... right?

Riiiiiiiiight... ;-)
